# MS List Gallery View Background Colour of Cards cannot be Updated

Tags: json, list, background, microsoft-teams, kanban

I am creating a kanban board for my team on MS List. I have tried to follow a few guides on the Internet. However, I am unable to change the background colour of the cards in gallery view.

I am trying to have 2 different colours based on the category of the task. I have used the internal field name which I have gotten from the url. There are no syntax errors with the json and the cards did not disappear (which meant the code worked but not for the background colour of the cards).

Any idea what I should do in this case?

Thank you.

I have used the internal field name which I have gotten from the url. There are no syntax errors with the json and the cards did not disappear (which meant the code worked but not for the background colour of the cards).

Comment: Could you please provide more details on your issue? Are you sending the card in MS Teams chat?  Any repro steps would be really helpful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Our team is using MS List to create a task list in gallery view. We have tried to change the background colour of the cards based on category but to no avail, despite using internal field name. Thank you